# How to scrape a web page for the src of an image?

Tags: node.js, cheerio

Basically I am trying to get the image src from a webpage so I can then download the image. Everything I have tried does not work.

Also, I am fairly new to node.js and cheerio, so bear with me.

```
var  DilbertURL = 'http://Dilbert.com/strip/' + getDateTime();

request(DilbertURL, function (error, response, body) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(body);

    $('div.container-fluid').each(function(i, element){
      var src = $('.img-responsive img-comic').attr("src");

      console.log(src);

    });

});
```

Everything I have tried to get the src of the dilbert image does not work. it all comes back 'undefined'. The html for the image goes like this...

```
<img alt="Wally's Passion  - Dilbert by Scott Adams" 
class="img-responsive img-comic" height="280"    src="http://assets.amuniversal.com/dc0c4f80fd6e0132ef1a005056a9545d" 
width="900">
```

What exactly am i doing wrong?

Comment: `console.log` the `$` variable and ensure that the body is loading correctly first.

Comment: @WesFoster It is. I am able to load all href's and everything else. Just not the src of an image...

Comment: cross-domain ajax = forbidden, unless you've got CORS set up...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

change this line to

```
  var src = $('.img-responsive img-comic').attr("src");
```

this

```
  var src = $('.img-responsive.img-comic').attr("src");
```

The selector will now work as intended! no space is needed to show that both classes belong to the same element rather than something with .img-responsive with a child element called img-comic which clearly wont exist!

Cheers

Comment: @Treemonkey *Facepalm* Why is it always the stupidest easiest things?! Thank you very much though. This is correct.